# WPF - How to convert string to Control Type

Tags: wpf

In WPF, I have textbox with Name is "txt".

```
<TextBox x:Name="txt" Height="75" Width="75" />
```

In my code-behind, I declare string s = txt.
How can I convert string "str" to control type above Textbox so that I can access directly Textbox via variable "str" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly access to you control from your code behind thanks to its name :

```
this.txt.Text = "ok";
```

You should not use a string variable to access your control.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Really it's not access similar PHP

Comment: It is a very different programming model from PHP. You can consider XAML as a serialization language. When you add the TextBox tag you are creating an instance of the TextBox class, and this instance is accessible from the code behind thanks to its name.